# What is the ip address of the OpenStack metadata server, and how can I query it?

Tags: openstack

Where is the OpenStack metadata server located? What can I do query it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenStack by default has its metadata hosted at `169.254.169.254`, and you can get to it from any resource provisioned on OpenStack with,

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data
```

You can also substitute any date for `latest`. The list returned will look something like this,

```
ami-id
ami-launch-index
ami-manifest-path
block-device-mapping/
hostname
instance-action
instance-id
instance-type
local-hostname
local-ipv4
placement/
public-hostname
public-ipv4
public-keys/
reservation-id
```

You can then follow up by picking something like

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname
```

---

You can find more information here,

- https://docs.openstack.org/nova/train/user/metadata.html

Comment: We should note that `169.254.169.254` is a [link local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address).  A VM's hypervisor needs to route it to the actual metadata server.