# Does OpenStack meta data carry the remote-exec provisioner stanza?

Tags: terraform, openstack

I have a Terraform HCL file with a [`remote-exec` provisioner](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/resources/provisioners/remote-exec) that looks like this..

```
resource "openstack_compute_instance_v2" "sandboxvm" {
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [<<EOF
      echo "start of sandboxvm provision..."
    EOF
    ]
  }
}
```

I **know** `user-data` gets stored on the [OpenStack metadata server](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/17376/18965). I learned that the hard way when [I wrote this answer](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/15683/18965). Does the OpenStack metadata server have access to the script used by this provisioner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## No

Having just done tested the `remote-exec` provisioner it does not..

```
$ curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/
ami-id
ami-launch-index
ami-manifest-path
block-device-mapping/
hostname
instance-action
instance-id
instance-type
local-hostname
local-ipv4
placement/
public-hostname
public-ipv4
public-keys/
reservation-id
```